# Where is the coolant reservoir on my Nissan Caravan 1995?

Tags: nissan, coolant-reservoir

I have a Nissan Caravan 1995 VRGE24 and I just can't find the coolant reservoir. I can find the orange radiator cap on top of the radiator itself and a small tube leads to the back of the motor but vanishes there. Anyone any idea where the reservoir itself might be located? The car has more strange spots for reservoirs, for example the brake and clutch fluid is behind the steering wheel and the wiper fluid reservoir needs to be filled next to the trunk so it wouldn't surprise me if the coolant one is in a strange place as well.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coolant reservoir is located directly behind the driver's seat under the carpet (not in the floor, but in the raised part). Pop open the carpet, take out the black screw, and slide out the metal cover. It's a bit tight back there - but, that's where you'll find it!
Happy hunting